# Is it possible to create Kafka topics through StreamSets Data Collector (SDC)?

Tags: apache-kafka, streamsets

I am using StreamSets Data Collector (SDC) web tool to create a pipeline that transfers data from my local system to Kafka through a Kafka producer. However, I have to first manually create the topic in which I want to store my data. Is it possible to create the topic via StreamSets?

Comment: How would you be calculating the topic name, partition configuration?

Comment: It is actually possible to create topics via StreamSets. When we start a new pipeline which has Kafka Producer as the destination, StreamSets automatically creates a new topic if it doesn't already exist on the Kafka server. By default the topic created has only one partition. Is it possible to specify the configuration in StreamSets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Kafka is configured to auto-create topics. You can set `num.partitions` in [broker config](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs) to change the number of partitions per topic from its default value of `1`.

If you wanted to create the topic from the pipeline, you could trigger a [shell executor](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/index.html#Executors/Shell.html#concept_jsr_zpw_tz) from the [pipeline start event](https://streamsets.com/documentation/datacollector/latest/help/index.html#Event_Handling/EventFramework-Title.html#concept_amg_2qr_t1b) to [create a topic](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#quickstart_createtopic).

Note that it is not possible to create the topic from a stage event, since these fire after data is sent to destinations, and you would want the topic to exist before the pipeline starts sending data.